# SQL Creating database and user with email as username

Tags: mysql, sql

when i try to use $email in SQL query it won't work. How ever when i try to use testname and password then it will work fine. Can someowne please help me to run proper sql to create account and database. Thanks

testmail@mail.com
pass123

```
// Create database
        echo "<br><br>";
      #echo "$sql";
      $sql="CREATE DATABASE '{$email}'";

      if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
        {
        echo "<h2>Database <b>$email</b> created successfully!</h2>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
        }


          // Create user
      $sql = 'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'{$email}\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY \'{$password}\'';
      echo "<br><br>";
      #echo "$sql";
      if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
        {
        echo "<h2>User Created... <b>$email</b> created successfully!</h2>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Error creating database user: " . mysqli_error($con);
        }


            // Create user permissions

      $sql = 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \'{$email}\' TO \'{$email}\'@\'localhost\'';
      echo "<br><br>";
      #echo "$sql";
      if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
        {
        echo "<h2>User permissions Created... <b>$email</b> created successfully!</h2>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Error creating database user: " . mysqli_error($con);
        }
```

Comment: when you echo the result of `'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'{$email}\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY \'{$password}\''`, where `$email` contains an `@`-symbol for itself, will the resulting sql statement work when copied and executed in a query editor? Please try out.

Comment: You can't use "@" in the db name. SQL uses that symbol to identify user variables in procedures and function, etc. Consider replacing that character with an underscore.